# How to search Mysql for multiple fields when one of the fields might be missing?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am running a wordpress site.

I need to query the database for users that have EITHER of 2 meta key sets.  See code below.  Users can be assigned meta values g, h, i, and j.  If all 4 are set, my AND / OR in the code works fine.
But if only 2 are set, it doesn't find the user at all.  I'm assuming this is because mysql recognizes the values as blank (or not set, because sometimes they're not even in the usermeta), and therefore cannot perform math on them.

Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do, allowing for meta values i and j to be blank, or not set?

```
select distinct a.ID 
from wp_users as a ,
wp_usermeta as b ,
wp_usermeta as g ,
wp_usermeta as h ,
wp_usermeta as i ,
wp_usermeta as j ,
where 1=1 and b.user_id = a.ID and g.user_id = a.ID and h.user_id = a.ID and i.user_id = a.ID and j.user_id = a.ID and g.meta_key='_blat' and h.meta_key='_blng' and i.meta_key='_hlat' and j.meta_key='_hlng' and a.ID NOT IN (0) and b.meta_key = 'last_name'
AND ( ( ( ( ( 35.2091855 - g.meta_value ) / 2 ) + ( -89.7989767 - h.meta_value ) / 2) < 16.09344 ) 
OR ( ( ( ( 35.2091855 - i.meta_value ) / 2 ) + ( -89.7989767 - j.meta_value ) < 16.09344 ) ) ) 
order by b.meta_value asc 
limit 0,25
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, what the needed result should be if a meta value is not set.

How about using IFNULL(g.meta_value, 0). This will return zero if g.meta_value ist not set (null).

I mean changing the following line to;

```
OR ( ( ( ( 35.2091855 - IFNULL(i.meta_value, 0) ) / 2 ) + ( -89.7989767 - IFNULL(j.meta_value, 0) ) < 16.09344 ) ) )
```

If i and j are not set this will result in -72.19438395 < 16.09344 which will always return TRUE. Cannot figure out if this helps though, or what the condition should result in if i and j are not set ...

Comment: That's worth a try - I'll try it and see if it works.  I can force i and j to be set if I need to (they'll just be null).  Thanks so much!

Comment: Thank you, that worked well.  I had run into a problem with it, but it turned out the user had a different problem with his record.  Thank you for understanding my request, and your rapid reply!